# How do you create a query to hide all posts with a certain meta key, unless current user is the author of that post, without custom SQL?

Tags: query, author

The scenario, which I would have thought is quite common, could be where a blog post has been assigned a particular meta, and should be removed from public display, apart from the original author who should retain access to it.

I have considered:

1. pre_get_posts - before the query is run, we can't access the post to determine the author
2. pre_get_posts with a second query, using author__not_in and the meta query to generate a list of all posts the current author shouldn't see, and pass that into the main query as posts__not_in. You can't merge queries that way, memory problems a plenty, recursion, ahhhh!
3. the_post - this is an action, not a filter. It can't be used to remove a post.
4. the_posts - unsetting a particular array key in a foreach didn't work, and seems resource heavy?
5. Add another postmeta 'author' and then creating an AND meta query. Absolutely mad. The author is already attached to the post. It would then be wrong if the author was changed subsequently.
6. Custom SQL - I really, really want to believe there is a better way before I revert to creating custom queries. I would then have to dive deep into it for every other piece of query work I need to do for this project. I have already used pre_get_posts and other filters elsewhere, and don't want to rewrite everything.

Does anyone have an obvious answer they've used, or any other possible methods to try?